# Blender 2.70 Fly Mode Camera: How Do I Change the Camera "Height" For Gravity?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

In the new 2.70 fly mode, pressing TAB causes the camera to fall and hit any relatively flat surface (in Z axis).  However, when viewing scaled scenes at an arbitrary scaling, the camera falls really really far as though the "person" is incredibly tiny within the scene that you are walking through.

How do I change the camera/person's pov/player height so that I can fit in my scaled scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the properties of fly navigation (including view height) in *User preferences > Input > View Navigation*:

[image]

Even if it's grayed out because the *Gravity* checkbox is disabled, changing the value will still affect the view hight when gravity is enabled by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while in fly navigation mode.