# Issues at both little and large scales, not understanding the render

Tags: rendering, memory-management, scale

I have serious trouble understanding this:

1.- When i work on my project, im building a house into a mountain but "walk mode" seems to tell me that my project is very little, as I cannot walk into the tunnel.

2.- When I resize it up to 100x, I can walk into the tunnel, but if I make a mistake with the mousewheel and zoom out too far, memory dumps out and stops showing my project, because it is too far, even there is a point where half my mountain is shown, and half my mountain is not, which i guess its RAM or GPU issues (4gb DDR3/2 MB integrated radeon graphics)

3.- When I want to add a "sky texture" to my world, I am forced to travel through my file in "Rendered view" but it takes years to load very slow, and can even overheat my pc

4.- Happens to appear like i cannot work in both little and big scales, untill i  upgrade my GPU/RAM but when I play games, why does it render too fast compared  to blender and why cant blender do this aswell? Do you know a better way to walk into my tunnel without having memory issues as if I were playing a game?

Thanks in advance, I would attach my .blender but this https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ gets stuck at "Processing files may take a whole" advice

Comment: See if these help at all https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed and you may have to apply scale depending on your scene.

Comment: Related to 1): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8813/37728

Comment: Question to 3): How do you add the sky texture? Why does it not work in other views?